# Remove sale order grid total count in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, order-grid

I am on **Magento 1.9** and would like to remove one of the block in

> sales -> orders page

**See attachment**. Can someone please show me **which file that i need to edit** in order to remove that?

[image: block]

Comment: Why do you want to remove this? this is a good feature of magento

Comment: I know it is a good feature but we just need to temporarily remove it. if you can provide me which file to edit, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Comment: i followed the instruction but it did not work. thanks anyway. We found solution ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a good feature of magento, and since you want to remove it temporarily, please follow these instruction.

Open file:

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml

Find this line:

```
<td class="pager">
```

In inner html of this td tag add this condition for whole block

```
<?php if($this->getRequest()->getControllerName() != "sales_order") { ?>
```

And before closing tag of `</td>` add use `<?php } ?>`

I didn't find any other solution to remove it. And since you are doing it temporarily it is better to use this condition and remove it if you want to re-enable this feature.